# Exclude outer node in marshalling of List<X>

Tags: jaxb

```
public class Group {
    //many other fields
    public List<Person> persons;
}

public class Person {
    public String name; ...
}
```

When I marhsal I want to get a bunch of Person nodes:

> ```
> <person>
>     <name>..</name>
> </person>
> <person>
>     <name>..</name>
> </person>
> ```

instead of this: (a persons node with person nodes as children)

> ```
> <persons>
>     <person>
>       <name>..</name>
>     </person>
>     <person>
>       <name>..</name>
>     </person>
> <persons>
> ```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: That should be how it appears by default, unless there is an `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation on the `persons` property.  If there is one, try removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If you are referring to `persons` as a grouping element rather than a root element a [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation does not add one by default.

**Group (Without Grouping Element)**

```java
package forum13305973;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Group {
    //many other fields
    @XmlElement(name="person")
    public List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

**Person**

```java
package forum13305973;

public class Person {
    public String name;
}
```

**Demo**

```java
package forum13305973;

import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Group.class);

        Group group = new Group();

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.name = "Jane";
        group.persons.add(person1);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.name = "John";
        group.persons.add(person2);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(group, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<group>
    <person>
        <name>Jane</name>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>John</name>
    </person>
</group>
```

---

**Group (With Grouping Element)**

You need to add an `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation to get a grouping element

```java
package forum13305973;

import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Group {
    //many other fields
    @XmlElementWrapper
    @XmlElement(name="person")
    public List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
}
```

**Output (With Grouping Element)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<group>
    <persons>
        <person>
            <name>Jane</name>
        </person>
        <person>
            <name>John</name>
        </person>
    </persons>
</group>
```

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You could do the following:

```java
    JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Person.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true); // format output
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true); // remove header

    for(Person person : group.persons) {
        marshaller.marshal(person, System.out);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about incomplete info but actually, the Group class has many other fields as well. If I do as you suggest, then I think I would need to marshall all the other fields separately as well? I was hoping to marshal the whole Group class in one go.