# How can I exclude some attributes with JAXB to be convertet to xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xmlwriter

In the Link below is perfectly explained how to write objects into an XML-File.
My Question ist, how can I beware some Attributes to be written into the XML-File?

[This is the Link I mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305973/exclude-outer-node-in-marshalling-of-listx)

For Example:

```
public class Human{

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private DateMinutesHours birthday;

    public Human(nam, ag, bir){

        this.name = nam;
        this.age= ag;
        this.birthday= bir;
    }

    @XmlElement( name = "lastname")
    public getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    @NotAnXmlElement << Do something like this exist? 
    public getAge(){
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Exclude Less Than Half of the Properties

You can use the `@XmlTransient` annotation on the property to exclude it from being written to XML.

### Exclude More Than Half of the Properties

If you are excluding a lot of properties then you can specify `@XmlAccessorType (XmlAcceessType.NONE)` on the class.  This means that only things you explicitly annotate will be converted to/from XML.